# Resize UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader

Tags: objective-c, header, resize, uicollectionview

I'm trying to resize a UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader but a didn't find any way.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`UICollectionViewDataSource`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewDataSource_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012175-CH1-SW6) Protocol method:

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {

   // dequeue your resuable headerview and set your custom frame here...

   return headerView;
}
```

Also, if you are implementing the [`UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012181-CH1-SW7) Protocol, you can use the following method to adjust the size of section headers that are already dequeued:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

   CGSize headerViewSize = CGSizeMake(300, 40);

   return headerViewSize;
}
```

Comment: I can change the headerView size. But the layout of whole collection view is not refreshes so that the header will be overlapped with collectionviewcell.

Comment: I have the same question. resize headerView is easy, but the problem is `collectionView.reloadData` will not change the collectionView body' y value to fit the new headerView size